# Update table rows that are equal to view row

Tags: sql, while-loop, sql-update

I have view that contains representation of duplicate guids

```
GUID
----
1234
5524
1111
```

Then I have table like that:

```
ID|SomeColumn|GUID
--+----------+----
1 |value1    |1111
2 |value1    |1112
3 |value1    |1113
4 |value1    |5524
5 |value1    |1234
```

I want to create loop that walk through that table and update those rows where GUID equal that view(table) GUID.

I tied this:

```
UPDATE DT
    SET [GUID] = dbo.CREATE_UNIQUE_GUID(ID)
    FROM [DetailsTable] as DT
    INNER JOIN GUID_Duplicates as GD
        ON DT.GUID=GD.GUID
        WHERE DT.GUID=GD.GUID
```

And have : *Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'UPDATE' within a function.*

So in pseudo-code I want to:

foreach duplicate in Duplicate Table if DataTable contains row with same GUID set GUID to new generated value.

Note: that I have guid generation working so I just not sure how to brows trough that DataTable using each value of view.
Also DataTable can have multiple rows where GUID is equal to each GUID from View.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, show the programming block where you have this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use directly SELECT clause for UPDATE statement :

```
 UPDATE [DetailsTable] SET [DetailsTable].[GUID] = dbo.CREATE_UNIQUE_GUID(ID)
 FROM [GUID_Duplicates]
 WHERE [DetailsTable].GUID = [GUID_Duplicates].GUID
```

Comment: If the original query fails, this will fail.

Comment: That is better query than my, I like it. But probably reason was as I used my inside function. Thanks.